# WPF control with many GridViews

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls, itemssource

I have a WPF user control that will dynamically have any number of `GridView`s. Each is essentially the exact same except for the `ItemsSource`. Therefore each have the same columns and the same `RowDetailsTemplate`. To be specific what I am actually doing is settings the columns to the bound values and then setting the `RowDetailsTemplate` to the data template.

What is the best approach to essentially define the `GridView` once and copy it to all the others. I have tried `XamlWriter.Save` with the `GridView` in the resources, but the columns and `RowDetailsTemplate` are not saved. I have also tried a style, but the columns property is not settable.

Maybe I did something wrong with the two approaches.

Comment: Why do you have multiple GridViews, instead of rebinding a single one?

Comment: Each pertain to a section of data and it logically makes sense to keep them apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` with `ItemTemplate`. The `DataTemplate` used for the `Itemtemplate` should contain the GridView XAML with all the column definitions. Next bind the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemSource` to a collection of whatever data object you want the `GridView`s to use as `ItemSource`.